# Por que me devuelve valores repetidos? SQLServer C#

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy almacenando en un objeto X unos valores para luego realizar una consulta SQLServer mediante esos valores.

El problema me viene a la hora de querer mostrar los registros que me devuelve esa consulta, que parece que en vez de almacenar en lista cada uno de los registros, me añade todo el rato el objeto construido con los mismos atributos, por lo que el programa no realiza su función y me devuelve todo el rato los mismos valores.

Dejo unos pantallazos y el cacho del código en cuestión con el que estoy teniendo los problemas.

**Extracto del código donde se genera el conflicto.**

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ALQUILERES WHERE GETDATE() < DATEADD(dd, 2, FECHAALQUILER)";
        redVideoClub.Open();
        comando = new SqlCommand(query, redVideoClub);
        registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
        while (registro.Read())
        {
            Dev = new Alquiler() { FechaALQ = a2.FechaALQ, IDPelicula = a2.IDPelicula, IDCliente = a2.IDCliente };
            AlquileresDev.Add(Dev);
        }
        redVideoClub.Close();
        foreach (Alquiler item in AlquileresDev)
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM PELICULAS WHERE ID = " + Dev.IDPelicula;
            redVideoClub.Open();
            comando = new SqlCommand(query, redVideoClub);
            registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (registro.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(registro[0].ToString() + " | " + registro[1].ToString());
            }
            redVideoClub.Close();

        }
```

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: He dejado el cacho del código que no cumple su funcion de manera optima. La otra parte solo es para que se pueda leer a grandes rasgos y entender el contexto del programa.

Comment: El código que muestras **no guarda en ningún registro**.

Comment: @SJuan76 Perdona, igual me he explicado mal, soy muy nuevo aún en esto. El problema es que a la hora de mostrar los registros a traves del Foreach me muestra en pantalla todo el rato el mismo, por lo que pienso que no se puede estar almacenando bien los objetos en la lista. Edito y expando el código a ver si se entiende mejor.

Comment: Además, [te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)

Comment: Pues lo siento, desconocía que no se podìa poner lo de urgente.

Comment: @Isaak, edita tu pregunta y elimina las imágenes entonces, por favor. Si el código publicado _da contexto_, entonces publica el texto del código como tal. Un saludo.

Comment: @Isaak, es _recomendable_ no ponerlo por las razones expuestas en el link. Si te lo comento, es para ayudarte a obtener respuesta.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, para otra vez lo voy a tener en cuenta. De todas maneras ya esta solucionado. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo :)

Comment: No pongas SOLUCIONADO, así no funciona la plataforma, en su lugar acepta la respuesta que te ayudó y marcala

Comment: @Aprendiz Perdona pero como marco la respuesta? Lo siento, aun no se utilizar bien esta plataforma.

Comment: da clic en el símbolo de *palomita* o *tick* que esta a la izquierda de la zona de votos, donde están las flechas hacia arriba y hacia abajo

Comment: Lee: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y no es mala idea que hagas el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puede ser por que dev nunca cambia dentro de tu ciclo foreach

Dev.IDPelicula en la consulta dentro del foreach no cambia

```
query = "SELECT * FROM PELICULAS WHERE ID = " + Dev.IDPelicula;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que me pasaba! De verdad muchas gracias, gracias a ti ya tengo el trabajo listo. :D

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios problema en ese codigo

- Usas una instancia globla en el primer caundo iteras la primer consulta para añadir a la lista. No se si sabes como funcionana los objetos, pero estos son por referencia por lo tanto se van pisando porque todos apuntan a la misma direccion de memoria. 
  Debes definir el ambito de la variable lo mas local posible
- No usas parametros en las consulta, no es una buena practica concatenar en un string los valores

Analiza este codigo

```
redVideoClub.Open();

string query = "SELECT * FROM ALQUILERES WHERE GETDATE() < DATEADD(dd, 2, FECHAALQUILER)";

SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, redVideoClub);
var registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
while (registro.Read())
{
    Alquiler Dev = new Alquiler() { FechaALQ = a2.FechaALQ, IDPelicula = a2.IDPelicula, IDCliente = a2.IDCliente };
    AlquileresDev.Add(Dev);
}

string query2 = "SELECT * FROM PELICULAS WHERE ID = @id";
SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(query2, redVideoClub);

foreach (Alquiler item in AlquileresDev)
{
    comando2.Parameters.Clear();
    comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.IDPelicula)
    var registro2 = comando2.ExecuteReader();
    while (registro2.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", registro2[0], registro2[1]);
    }

}

redVideoClub.Close();
```